# How do I transform a xsd file into a SQL Server table?

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, entity-framework, xsd

I would like to turn a XSD file into a SQL Server table. Is there anyway to do this without using the tool XSD2DB because I already tried it and does not work .

In fact what I would like to do is to persist information of an object in the database. I already have a class that I created from XSD and it has about 400 properties. I don't want to have to manually create 400 columns in a table database ...

I've already tried to create a code that does an INSERT, but I don't think it is the best way to do it; it would be huge ugly and inefficient. I could use Entity Framework however with the tutorials that I've seen on the Internet you have to create a Data Model based on a previously existing table in the database ... Is there any other way to do this ?

Thank you all!

Comment: If you already have a class object representing the model you need, then you can write a datacontext class and EF will do all the heavy lifting for you. Plenty of resources online if you search for EF CodeFirst.

Comment: Have you considered using the Xml Type?